# Accessibility question: do select dropdown elements need to be tab-able to go up/down the menu?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I've been trying to find an answer to this, but can't quite get a clear one. I'm using a [MUI Select](https://mui.com/components/selects/) component in my app, and noticed that it the menu items are able to be navigated with up/down keys and selected with the enter key, but not able to go up/down with the tab key. Is this a best practice for accessibility, or is it not required? I also looked at [this guideline](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/combobox-select-only.html), which seems like tabbing isn't required. Just want need some validation on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the different options of a dropdown menu, no, they shouldn't be reachable with <kbd>tab</kbd>.

This is probably more a common convention  or a recommandation than an absolute obligation, as far as I know.
It comes from native UI control/widget/component conventions on most operating systems that have been in use long time before the web.

The <kbd>tab</kbd> key is normally used to go from a control to the next.
But when you go through the different options of a dropdown menu, you stay on the same control.
So dropdown options don't have to, and even really shouldn't be reachable with the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

The same answer applies on the different tabs of a tab control, or the items in a list of selectable items. Normally when navigating with tab, you should only reach the currently selected / active element. Another press on tab key moves to the next interactive control.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, the goal of TAB is typically to move from a specific input control.to another, not within it.  Thus, the use of arrow keys and enter is fine.  However as a screen reader user myself, I run across custom "selection" boxes that fail to work properly due to many reasons.   even if keyboard navigation works as expected outside of a screen reader context.  It isn't clear  to me if you tried this under a screen reader.